# Can I manipulate a hashmap to store multiple datatypes?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a hashmap that stores a key as String and an Integer as Value.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> Items;
```

I would like to store multiple datatypes in this and what I have looked up would only solve the problem if all of the value elements of the Hashmap were of the same datatype.

Is there anyway to have multiple datatypes in a Hashmap like so

```
HashMap<String, Integer, BigDecimal, Date> items;
```

I know its possible to store multiple values of one of these datatypes as something like an arraylist but that still only allows me to chose one datatype.

Is there another collection I could use that allows multiple datatypes to be stored?

Thanks

Comment: Just throwing this out there... why?

Comment: This question smells *strongly* of being an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sure you could use a non-generic Map, but the bigger question is 1) **why** would you want to do this, and 2) likely there are much better approaches to solving whatever overall problem you're trying to solve. My suggestion: look for these other approaches. If you need our help, improve the question by telling us more of the overall problem, not the problematic way you're trying to solve it.

Comment: How about `HashMap<String, OtherClassWithTheFieldsYouWant>`

Comment: @JoeC: Yep, you said in few words what I struggled to say in many.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a superclass of all the types you want to store. If you want to store different types of numbers you could for example do

```
HashMap<String, Number> items;
```

You can go all the way up to `Object` with this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> items;
```

allowing you to store basically anything in there.

However, depending on what you're doing this can negatively affect performance through the possible necessity of `instanceof`-checks and casting.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap these data types into a class which overrides `hashCode` and `equals`.  (I leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

```
public class Amalgam {
    private Integer field1;
    private BigDecimal field2;
    private Date field3;
}
```

Then you can use a `Map` straightforwardly.

```
Map<String, Amalgam> items = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
HashMap<String, Object> items;
```

But you have to be careful when you retrieve the items

Comment: *"you have to be careful"* is not too helpful, you might want to elaborate on that part.

Comment: @domdom oh come on !! :P

Comment: "You have to be careful" is generous at *best*.  Careful doesn't even describe it.  You have to basically know what each value type is at each key.

Comment: @Makoto Well more or less. You could always do instanceof-checks, but this would obviously cripple the performance.

Comment: @Makoto I was leaving that to the reader as an exercise ;)